# Sorting and filtering a list of custom object dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, listview

I need some help. I have a list of custom object and I need to filtering and ordering it dynamically.

This list is the datasource of my datagridview.

I would like to do the ordering when the `datagridview.columnHeaderMouseClick` event occurs, dynamically passing the column name to the where clause.

I have something like this:

```
Private sub   DatagridView1_columnHeaderMouseClick (sender As Object, e As  DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handlers DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick    
    ' Here I get the name of the column pressed        
    Dim columnName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName

    ' I need to do the following        
    AccountOfMoneyBindingSource.DataSource = accounts.orderBy(Function(x) x.columnName)        
    ' Where columnName is Dinamically passed
```

I tried with Dynamic LINQ using a string how I saw in some examples but I got a error.

Comment: So show us what you tried and tell us what the error was because that is the problem we're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example class.

```
Public Class Coffee
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property ID As Integer
        Public Sub New(coffeeName As String, coffeeID As Integer)
            Name = coffeeName
            ID = coffeeID
        End Sub
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"{Name} - {ID}"
        End Function
End Class
```

And here is the code to sort your list by a particular Property of the class.

```
Private Sub SortList()
    Dim OriginalList As New List(Of Coffee)
    Dim SortedList As List(Of Coffee) = OriginalList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()
End Sub
```

You can sort your list and rebind it to the DataGridView.

**EDIT**

```
Private Sub SortList(ColumnName As String)
    Dim OriginalList As New List(Of Coffee)
    Dim SortedList As List(Of Coffee) = Nothing
    Select Case ColumnName
        Case "Name"
            SortedList = OriginalList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()
        Case "ID"
            SortedList = OriginalList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ID).ToList()
    End Select
    DataGridView1.DataSource = SortedList
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am looking for is to be able to pass the attribute Name dinamically. That is, without knowing previously it. My object has many attribute. I try to avoid have to program the orderBy clause for each one

Comment: Thanks. That is not neither what I am looking for. I would like make something generic. That is, not necessarily knowing the name of the parameters of my object previously, but get it by pressing a column.

Comment: This in order to be able to use lists of different objects

Comment: In the example above, use a case statement to determine which filter to apply. This forces me to know all the attributes that the object has and therefore have to program this for each list of objects. I do not know if I explain myself very well